# How do I create a fragment template(class with variables and methods, layout) for multiple fragments with the same content?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

On the main screen I have 7 buttons (days) and a fragment.
For every day of the week I wanted to generate a fragment with some EditTexts and a ListView, but creating 7 fragments with the same layout and almost the same class content seems too repetitive.
I only did it for Monday and Tuesday.

The only difference between MondayFragment and TuesdayFragment is that in TuesdayFragment I renamed the variable mondayTV to tuesdayTV and in layout I changed the ids of the submit button and the ListView. Also the key for Bundle is different. I don't think it's worth posting it since it's so similar to MondayFragment.

I want to know if it's possible to create a fragment template and use it to generate a fragment for every button of the activity given this code I wrote. There is still a lot to work on when it comes to functionality but I can't get this idea out of my head.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dietmanagement;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday;

    final MondayFragment mondayFragment = new MondayFragment();
    final TuesdayFragment tuesdayFragment = new TuesdayFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*Intent i = getIntent();
        String current_user = i.getStringExtra("current_user");
        TextView current_user_txtview = findViewById(R.id.current_user);
        current_user_txtview.setText("Welcome, " + current_user);*/

        monday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.monday_btn);
        tuesday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tuesday_btn);
        wednesday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wednesday_btn);
        thursday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thursday_btn);
        friday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.friday_btn);
        saturday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saturday_btn);
        sunday = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sunday_btn);

        monday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFragment(mondayFragment);
                getDay(mondayFragment, "monday", (String) monday.getContentDescription());
            }
        });


        tuesday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFragment(tuesdayFragment);
                getDay(tuesdayFragment, "tuesday", (String) tuesday.getContentDescription());
            }
        });

    }

    private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.daysfragment, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void getDay(final Fragment fragment, String key, String value)
    {
        Bundle bnd = new Bundle();
        bnd.putString(key, value);
        fragment.setArguments(bnd);
    }

}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_green"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tuesday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tuesday_context"
        android:text="@string/tuesday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.194"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/monday_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_title"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/welcome_label"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.414"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.049" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/monday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:contentDescription="@string/monday_context"
        android:text="@string/monday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/thursday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:text="@string/thursday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.018"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.172" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sunday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:text="@string/sunday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.786"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/saturday_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.172" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saturday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:text="@string/saturday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.225"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/friday_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.172" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/friday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:text="@string/friday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.137"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thursday_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.172" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wednesday_btn"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:text="@string/wednesday"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.369"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tuesday_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.017" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/current_user"
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:text="@string/current_user"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.938"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.318" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/daysfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MondayFragment.java

```
    package com.example.dietmanagement;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MondayFragment extends Fragment {

    public TextView mondayTV;
    public ArrayList<String> hour_food;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter;
    public ListView listView;
    public EditText input_meal;
    public EditText input_time;
    public Button submit;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday, container, false);

        mondayTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day);
        Bundle bndMon = getArguments();
        String day = bndMon.getString("monday");
        mondayTV.setText(day);

        hour_food = new ArrayList<String>();
        listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hour_food);
        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.monday_list_item);

        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                hour_food.remove(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Meal Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });

        input_meal = v.findViewById(R.id.input_meal);
        input_time = v.findViewById(R.id.input_time);

        submit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit_food_btn);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input_time.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Empty time input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input_meal.getText())){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Empty meal input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    hour_food.add(String.format("%s - %s", input_meal.getText().toString(), input_time.getText().toString()));
                    listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    input_meal.setText("");
                    input_time.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

fragment_monday.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_green"
    tools:context=".MondayFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/day" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="@string/time"
            android:hint="@string/time"
            android:inputType="time" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_meal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="@string/meal"
            android:hint="@string/meal"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_food_btn_monday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/background_green"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/monday_list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

Comment: Maybe take a look at abstract classes

Comment: Why do your fragments have different layouts at all? It seems like everyone could be an instance of a `DayOfTheWeekFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Create `DayFragment` and layout only for one day. Pass extra information for `Fragment` and handle situations for different days with that extra information (in your case it looks like only `String` from bundle is different).

fragment_day.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_green">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/day" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="@string/time"
            android:hint="@string/time"
            android:inputType="time" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_meal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="@string/meal"
            android:hint="@string/meal"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_food_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/background_green"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

DayFragment.java

```
public class DayFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView dayTV;
    private ArrayList<String> hour_food;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private EditText input_meal;
    private EditText input_time;
    private Button submit;
    private String text;

    public DayFragment(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day, container, false);

        dayTV = v.findViewById(R.id.day);
        dayTV.setText(text);

        hour_food = new ArrayList<>();
        listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hour_food);
        listView = v.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            hour_food.remove(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Meal Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        });

        input_meal = v.findViewById(R.id.input_meal);
        input_time = v.findViewById(R.id.input_time);

        submit = v.findViewById(R.id.submit_food_btn);
        submit.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(input_time.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Empty time input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(input_meal.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Empty meal input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                hour_food.add(String.format("%s - %s", input_meal.getText().toString(), input_time.getText().toString()));
                listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                input_meal.setText("");
                input_time.setText("");
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Use constructor for passing information.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button monday = findViewById(R.id.monday_btn),
                tuesday = findViewById(R.id.tuesday_btn),
                wednesday = findViewById(R.id.wednesday_btn),
                thursday = findViewById(R.id.thursday_btn),
                friday = findViewById(R.id.friday_btn),
                saturday = findViewById(R.id.saturday_btn),
                sunday = findViewById(R.id.sunday_btn);

        openFragment(monday);
        openFragment(tuesday);
        openFragment(wednesday);
        openFragment(thursday);
        openFragment(friday);
        openFragment(saturday);
        openFragment(sunday);
    }

    private void openFragment(Button btn) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String contentDescription = btn.getContentDescription().toString();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.daysfragment, new DayFragment(contentDescription))
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        });
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity` `openFragment()` method takes a `Button` parameter and with that `Button` and sets onClickListener to that `Button`. When you click any `Button` it gets content description from that `Button` and passing it to `Fragment` and opens that `Fragment` with that content description.